# Android: How to write SDK specific Code?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm new to Android programming. I want to write some custom animation which is supported only in the latest Android 5.0 (API 21). I would like to know what is the best/recommended way to write SDK specific code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= SOME_SDK_VERSION) {
   // write api specific code here?
}
```

Is the above method the right way to do it? For example, if there are multiple SDK specific API calls, should I wrap everything in an above format?

Comment: I think yes. You can +

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can always do this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   // code for Lollipop and later
}
```

This will work even on pre-Lollipop devices (because the version code is inlined at compile time and `SDK_INT` is not).

Comment: Is there any `android` way of doing this? I mean the code will end up with lot of if checks in this way for each sdk version.

Comment: What do you mean by "android way"? This is the standard way; even the classes in the support library use checks like this. You can abstract away some of it by making an interface and a series of classes that implement the interface, and choose which implementation based on SDK version, but it still basically uses the same check.